# Azure Devops compare PR shows the file old status after a squash merge

Tags: azure-devops

Something strange happened with my branches and PR. So basically I have squash merged a feature branch into my main branch but I forgot to delete the feature branch.  A few days later I have recognized feature branch is still in the remote. I remember that I had merged this into the main but I wanted to make sure that there is no unmerged changes and I created compare PR to see the difference. Then suddenly it shows me many files changed which are already in main.
It is strange that PR is showing old status of the files on main. For example; below green  highlighted version is already the one in main. So main has this nugets 3.1.20 version

[image]

here the SS from main

[image]

same goes on other files. So why would this PR shows the old version of the file if I create the 2nd time? So it doesnt actually compare correctly?

I understand that older commits can be shown as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399079/azure-devops-pull-request-from-dev-to-master-is-fetching-old-code), not sure if it is the same issue but why file changes or differences should be different doing a second PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it is the same issue but why file changes or differences should be different doing a second PR?

Yes, you are right. This is same issue.

This is because of the specific way squash merge merges. Just as the Hugh said "Squash merging allows you to condense the commits of topic branches and adds them to a single **new commit** on the default branch."

The difference between it and regular merge is that it does not commit all the commits contained in the branch to the target branch, but **creates a new commit** to represent a commit of the current PR.

**For example**:

[image]

**Common PR**:

[image]

**squash merge**:

[image]

When we are doing PR, when we compare the source branch and the target branch, we judge the difference of the file according to the **records of commits on the two branches**, not the difference of the file itself. In this way, when we merge the PR with squash merge, those old commits are not merged into the target branch, so when comparing the files, the old changes will still be displayed.

That is the reason why PR shows the old version of the file if you create the 2nd time.

Comment: Is there a better way to compare files (not commits) if we arent sure there was merge in case like scenario above not removing the feature branch.

Comment: @Emil, Files can be compared with the help of other third-party tools.

Comment: what is the easiest way to sync the branches?

Comment: I use GitLens in VS Code to compare branches. I tested the scenario that OP laid out and GitLens has the same exact behavior as AzDO. If you find yourself in this situation, the easiest way to see the diffs is to jump to your feature branch and rebase your main brain (`git rebase main`), save your new rebase as a branch, and then use GitLens to compare that with main. You could also use `difftool` if you have that set up. Or you could create a throwaway PR and look at the diff in AzDO.